# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting some weird error with the following bit of code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
            $stmt = $this->registry->db->getDB()->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` (date_posted,comment) VALUES ?,?");
        $stmt->execute(array($date,$comment));
```

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ''2015-04-27 15:26:31','Very good'' at line 1
>   in C:\wamp\www\model\qualityControlModel.class.php on line 161

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: please take the time to read up on how to use prepared statements. It would have avoided this question entirely.

Comment: How come everyone reports their errors as *"weird"*?

Comment: *Yeah eh Sam?*  that's just weird @JayBlanchard

Comment: Aren't we all just really *weird Ralph?* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Only after the crescent moon *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Did you check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2015-04-27 15:26:31','Very good'' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\model\qualityControlModel.class.php on line 161?

Seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Jay's posted an answer for you below. See if that makes it kick in to 3rd gear ;-)

Comment: *"@Fred-ii- Shut up –  user3574492 39 secs ago "* - that's the thanks I get. *pfft* get bent

Comment: plus, I honestly don't see why you took my comment as offensive, I mean really. I thought it was rather fun! so I didn't "deserve" that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the query line includes all of the parentheses, including those surrounding the `VALUES`:

```
$stmt = $this->registry->db->getDB()->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` (date_posted,comment) VALUES (?,?)");
```

Comment: We've got 1st gear, 2nd gear, [but no 3rd gear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898804/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax#comment47921641_29898804). OP probably hasn't rammed it in hard enough yet.